Ubuntu 24.04 Dotnet CLI core dump on .Net Core 3.1
I was following this tutorial from Digital Ocean about how to deploy a ASP .Net Core app with MySQL using Nginx on Ubuntu 24.04.
I've set up MySQL and Nginx successfully however I had a problem installing dotnet 2.2. After a quick search I found out that this is a common problem since 24.04 lacks libicu 57 and libssl 1.0.0.
I was able to download the .deb for libssl and use dpkg to install it however none of the links I found for the libicu 57(second link) was available.
So I opted out for dotnet 3.1 and resumed with the rest of the tutorial however I could not apply the migrations with the dotnet ef command:
Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support.
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
   at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode.GetGlobalizationInvariantMode()
   at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode..cctor()
   at System.Globalization.CultureData.CreateCultureWithInvariantData()
   at System.Globalization.CultureData.get_Invariant()
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..cctor()
   at System.String.ToLowerInvariant()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.RuntimeEnvironment.GetArch()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.RuntimeEnvironment..cctor()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeIdentifier()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.MulticoreJitProfilePathCalculator.CalculateProfileRootPath()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.MulticoreJitActivator.StartCliProfileOptimization()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.MulticoreJitActivator.TryActivateMulticoreJit()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(System.String[])
Aborted (core dumped)

As you can tell I'm new to using Linux for deployment. Should I downgrade ubuntu version or is there any recommendations?
Thanks in advance.
